# Why is my array buffer suddenly detaching?

Tags: node.js, arraybuffer, uwebsockets

I have the following uWebsockets application:

```js
const app = uWS.App({}).ws("/*", {
  message: (ws, bytes, isBinary) => {
    invariant(isBinary, "Websocket messages must be binary");
    const unpacked = unpack(Buffer.from(bytes));
    const msg = Message.parse(unpacked);
    console.log("AFTER PARSE")
    console.log(bytes);

    if (msg.kind === Codes.Selection || msg.kind === Codes.ClearSelection) {
      const { postId } = msg;
      republishMessage(app, postId, bytes);
      //echoMessage(ws, postId, bytes);
    } else if (msg.kind === Codes.Subscribe) {
      const { postId } = msg;
      handleSubscribe(ws, postId);
    } else if (msg.kind === Codes.CreateHighlight) {
      console.log("BEFORE HANDLER")
      console.log(bytes)
      handleCreateHighlight(app, bytes, msg);
    }
  },
});

// the problematic handler
export async function handleCreateHighlight(
  app: uws.TemplatedApp,
  bytes: ArrayBuffer,
  msg: CreateHighlightMessage
) {
  const { userId, range, postId } = msg;
  logger.info(`Highlight for ${postId} by ${userId}`);
  await db.Page.makeHighlight(postId as PageId, {
    userId: userId as UserId,
    range,
  });
  console.log("BEFORE REPUBLISH");
  console.log(bytes);
  await republishMessage(app, postId, bytes);
}
```

I've noticed some strange behavior inside the `handleCreateHighlight` handler. The `ArrayBuffer`, `bytes` is valid at the `"AFTER PARSE"` and `"BEFORE HANDLER"` `console.log` points. However, the `ArrayBuffer` is detached at the `"BEFORE REPUBLISH"` `console.log` point.

Why is the `ArrayBuffer` getting detached, and how do I prevent this from happening? Does this have to do with the fact that I'm using the `ArrayBuffer` after an `await` point?

Also for context, `pack` is a function from the [msgpackr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/msgpackr) library, which is an extremely fast MessagePack serializer/deserializer for Javascript.